# Upload iOS app to App Store with App Preview video in multiple languages

Tags: ios, video, app-store, app-preview

I've realized that the App Store interface doesn't let me uploading app preview videos in a language other than the main language of the app. Really? Am I missing something?

If it's like that, it doesn't make sense. Every person needs to see the video in his/her own language! Why limit the languages in the app preview video to just one?

Is there any workaround for this? We already filmed 30 second videos with an actress talking in different languages. We never imagined Apple would impose such a dumb limitation.

Comment: You can only have one app preview per device category. You can localize screenshots and metadata (description, what's new, keywords etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current time it doesn't seem possible to specify a localized App Preview.

From Apple's [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW34) documentation:

> The app preview you upload will be visible for all localizations.

and [this](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/) from Apple's App Preview developer overview page...

> Consider that your app preview is available in one language worldwide. Narration may not be appropriate in apps marketed globally. If you decide to use narration in your app preview, we recommend working with a professional voiceover actor. This is the voice of your app—make sure it resonates.

---

You can however specify localized *"metadata, keywords and screenshots"*.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH28-SW1):

> **Displaying on the Store in More Than One Language (Optional)**
>
> After you create an iTunes Connect record for your app, you can add the information for your primary localization and add additional localizations.
>
> For example, if you created the iTunes Connect record for your app with the primary language English, stores in all territories display information for the app in English. If you now upload metadata, keywords, and screenshots in French, users whose language is set to French or who are located in a territory that includes French (and not English) as a supported language see the French metadata instead of the English metadata. Your app is also searchable in all French-language stores by the localized keywords. In other store territories, the primary language, in this case English, appears.

---

Without seeing the content of your App Preview (or knowing more about your app), it is hard to make further suggestions. That said, the one's I can think of are really tradeoffs and would not utilize the multiple videos that you have already made.

Possible Tradeoffs:

- Choose the video most representative of your customer base. For example, if you primary customers are in Germany, choose the German video.
- Replace the voice narration with text annotations (possibly displaying the text in different languages in the same scene)
- Use localized screenshots
- Choose one video as your App Preview (for all localizations) and host all of the videos on a website and provide the link under "Developer's Website"

Comment: Can he transform his voice-actor into a metadata for the different stores?

Comment: @Sneak Sorry, not sure what you mean. Are you talking about taking the voice actor's narration and displaying it as localized text in the app's description? If so, then yes, this is possible.

Comment: My point was he asked for the video specifically since he has hired voice-actress and recorded videos, where text localization wont solve his issue with the recorded preview and the voice-actress.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It was certainly an oversight in our part not having thoroughly checked Apple's guidelines for app previews, but it seemed so obvious that you should be allowed to upload the video in several languages, just like you can do with screenshots, that we never thought about that. But now we have an even bigger problem. We've submitted our app including the app preview video in a single language, and now Apple has rejected it because the app preview video features a narrator! What?! That was certainly unexpected. The guidelines don't say anything against having a narrator!

Comment: From what I understand, I think they are OK with audio narration, but NOT OK with having an actual narrator person appearing on screen. They sure are nit-picky about everything!

Comment: @OMA Learn a lesson, especially when doing work in a company and not as a hobby - Apple has its appstore and guidelines, either you agree with it and use their services or you don't. They have WELL documented and even made VIDEO TUTORIALS for you to watch https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/

Comment: @Sneak : I can agree with you about the multiple languages problem (I should have read more extensively about that, though I still think it doesn't make sense not allowing videos in multiple languages, which Google does on Google Play, and Apple themselves do allow them with screenshots, so why not with videos?). BUT What about the "no narrator should be on screen" issue Apple also found with our video? That's completely random and NOT documented in their guidelines. They even say you can have narration! If they have a problem with having the narrator on screen they should clearly specify it.

Comment: @OMA Check my updated answer. You can read it says basically what you are allowed and not allowed to do. "previews may only use video screen captures of the app itself" . Since we have no visual example of your videopreview I cant comment on why it would get rejected.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I didn't get that detail because what I read was this instead: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/ . We did read the full App Store Review Guidelines back when we published our app a couple years ago or so (before app preview videos were available), so that information wasn't present back then. And now I did only read the info about App Previews in the aforementioned page dedicated solely to App Previews, which does not mention anything about only using screen captures.

Comment: It just says that "app previews use footage captured on device to show the experience of using your app", but it doesn't mention it should be the ONLY thing shown in the video. I didn't think it should be necessary to re-read the App Review guidelines, since the main change in our app was something external to the app (the app preview video), but I was wrong.

Comment: @OMA Yeah, things go really fast nowadays with their documentations changing with every update, not to mention all the functions getting deprecated etc that we all have to watchout for...its a jungle ... I feel you

Answer (score 1):

> Submitting App Previews Just like screenshots, each app preview is
>   device-specific and requires an iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Apple TV
>   to view and submit. Please note that you may only submit a single set
>   of app previews in one language localization. For detailed technical
>   specifications and step-by-step instructions on how to submit app
>   previews, read the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/)

EDIT UPDATE (Narrator OVERLAY Rejected):

> [2.3.4 Previews are a great](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) way for customers to see what your app looks like and what it does. To ensure people understand what they’ll
>   be getting with your app, previews may only use video screen captures
>   of the app itself. Stickers and iMessage extensions may show the user
>   experience in the Messages app. You can add narration and video or
>   textual overlays to help explain anything that isn’t clear from the
>   video alone.